# Fullpage js working fine localhost but not in live server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullpage.js

In my html code i'm using fullpage.js ,the web page is running fine on localhost but when i put all the files to server it's not running

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   if ($(window).width() > 768) {
      $('#fullpage').fullpage({         
        menu: '#side-menu',
        css3: true,
        scrollingSpeed: 1500,
        scrollBar: true,
        recordHistory: false
    });
   }
    else{     
   $.fn.fullpage.destroy('all');
  }   
});
```

[WEBSITE DEMO](https://www.bluemasons.com/hiw/howitworks.html)

Comment: `$(...).fullpage is not a function` / `/hiw/js/jquery.fullpage.js` 404 not found

Comment: Which version of jquery you are using?

Comment: look at this link  https://www.bluemasons.com/hiw/

you can see the fullpage.js here

Comment: Can i see picture of your folder structure ? it would be better if you provide screenshot i have faced same issue due to just capital - small letter problem in directory.

Comment: https://www.bluemasons.com/hiw/ in this link you would be able to see

Comment: Thank try this one it will work     <script src="js/jquery.fullPage.js"></script>
You have used small p ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one it will work `<script src="js/jquery.fullPage.js"></script>`

It's a matter of small/capital letters.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the network tab.

> The https://www.bluemasons.com/hiw/js/**jquery.fullpage.js** was not found.

The file is not hosted on this domain.